# gcloud app engine: How do i simply update source code of my PHP app?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud

When I've initialized my PHP Project in gcloud I used the following command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

as far as I understood that, it creates an image of a managed VM installs it in gcloud. This image also contains my source code. The deploy process can take a few minutes.

Since there are some use cases I can't test on my local machine, I need to test the deployed app.

So here's my question: Since the source code changes a lot during development and there's the necessity to test the changes again and again, oftenly in short intervals, do I always have to `deploy` the app?

Waiting a few minutes for deploying after a minor change is not satisfying...

If no, how else do I only update the source code?

Comment: You can run a local development server in order to test the changes without update the source code to gcloud. See this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server#running_the_local_development_server

Comment: well, but there's this note:
> Note: dev_appserver.py does not run in the App Engine flexible environment.
and i am using flexible environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker to do that. There is a docker image in github here is the link. You can use the flexible environment of gae

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docker

Comment: i am not sure, how this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the development app server which comes with google sdk. You then make your changes locally and only deploy once you're happy with the code i.e. once your ready to deploy a new feature. Hope that helped.

Comment: You can't use the development server for the flexible environment (or even for the 2nd generation standard environment) apps.